# React hook form, NumericFormat and MUI's TextField gives reference warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm using typescript and MUI for a Next js project, and I'm creating a form.
There's a numeric field meant for money and I want to validate all fields when submiting the form, so I'm using `yup`, `react-hook-form` and `react-number-format`. I've seen multiple examples that seem to be a bit old where they merge the `Controller` (form validation), `NumericFormat` (enforce a format to the user's input) and `TextField` (looks nice):

```
<Controller
    name="price"
    control={control}
    defaultValue={0}
    render={({field}) =>
        <NumericFormat
            {...field}
            customInput={TextField}
            value={field.value}
            onValueChange={(target) => {
                field.onChange(target.floatValue);
            }}
            allowLeadingZeros={false}
            prefix={'$ '}
            thousandSeparator=","
            margin="none"
            label="Price"
            fullWidth
        />
    }
/>
```

The issue is that I'm getting this warning in the console:

> client.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs.
> Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use
> React.forwardRef()?

Any explanation as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: MUI shows you how to use react-number-format and their TextField together in the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries). TextField should be the parent component and NumberFormat the inner (you currently have it around the other way).

Comment: That seemed to be the issue. I'll have to read a bit more on what forwardRef is. I tried just reading react-number-format repo's issues and examples but that was just misleading me more and more. I tested MUI doc's example and the validation also works. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one!

Comment: @JacobSmit Not really related to this specific issue, but do you happen to know how to reset a form when using NumericFormat? When I call the reset method everything works except for the TextFields that are using NumericFormat as inputComponents.

Comment: I think with how react-number-format works you have to pass it an empty string instead of a falsy value to get it to reset: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sw4bl1?file=Demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks for your help! In the end defining required fields that start as undefined or null with yup while using typescript is a nightmare. I had to restort to ts-ignore and reset the numeric fields as empty strings.